# Дата в Django. Утром на сервере с nginx показывает вчерашнее число, а на тестовом сегодня

Tags: python, django, datetime

При разработке в поле формы `datetime.now()` на сервере выводит вчерашнее число, хотя в settings.py указано `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Yekaterinburg'`. Сервер на Debian-nginx. В etc/init.d/nginx  добавили `export TZ="Asia/Yekaterinburg"`. Результат тот же. Сервер разработки (`manage.py runserver 8000`) выдает дату сегодня. Почему боевой сервер не выдает дату с учетом временной зоны? Что нужно куда прописать?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо datetime.now() используй localtime() из django.utils.timezone